# redis cluster TPS toooooo low, only 8

Tags: redis, benchmarking, redis-cluster

this is bench result

```
C:\Users\LG520\Desktop> redisbench -cluster=true -a 192.168.1.61:6380,192.168.1.61:6381,192.168.1.61:6382 -c 10 -n 100 -d 1000
2020/12/22 14:43:50 Go...
2020/12/22 14:43:50 # BENCHMARK CLUSTER (192.168.1.61:6380,192.168.1.61:6381,192.168.1.61:6382, db:0)
2020/12/22 14:43:50 * Clients Number: 10, Testing Times: 100, Data Size(B): 1000
2020/12/22 14:43:50 * Total Times: 1000, Total Size(B): 1000000
2020/12/22 14:46:13 # BENCHMARK DONE
2020/12/22 14:46:13 * TIMES: 1000, DUR(s): 143.547, TPS(Hz): 6
```

i build a redis cluster, but redisbench result is too low;

this is cluster info

```
[root@SZFT-LINUX chen]# ./redis-6.0.6/src/redis-cli -c -p 6380
127.0.0.1:6380> cluster info 
cluster_state:ok
cluster_slots_assigned:16384
cluster_slots_ok:16384
cluster_slots_pfail:0
cluster_slots_fail:0
cluster_known_nodes:6
cluster_size:3
cluster_current_epoch:6
cluster_my_epoch:1
cluster_stats_messages_ping_sent:2616
cluster_stats_messages_pong_sent:3260
cluster_stats_messages_sent:5876
cluster_stats_messages_ping_received:3255
cluster_stats_messages_pong_received:2616
cluster_stats_messages_meet_received:5
cluster_stats_messages_received:5876
127.0.0.1:6380> 
127.0.0.1:6380> cluster nodes
c12b3dbe5dbfe23a8bf0c180cbcdd6aaec98c4aa 192.168.1.61:6382@16382 master - 0 1608621050071 3 connected 10923-16383
3adf356189ddc44547b662b4f5f05f85f2cf016b 192.168.1.61:6385@16385 slave 8af6ca7a04368dd2cd7f40b76f3ac43fc0741812 0 1608621048057 2 connected
4a92459e43eff69aa6a0f603e13310b1a679b98d 192.168.1.61:6380@16380 myself,master - 0 1608621049000 1 connected 0-5460
72c20f23d93d87f75d78df4fa19e7cfa7a6f392e 192.168.1.61:6383@16383 slave c12b3dbe5dbfe23a8bf0c180cbcdd6aaec98c4aa 0 1608621048000 3 connected
fd16d8cd8226d3e6ee8854f642f82159c97eaa48 192.168.1.61:6384@16384 slave 4a92459e43eff69aa6a0f603e13310b1a679b98d 0 1608621047049 1 connected
8af6ca7a04368dd2cd7f40b76f3ac43fc0741812 192.168.1.61:6381@16381 master - 0 1608621049060 2 connected 5461-10922
127.0.0.1:6380>
```

redis version: 6.0.6

i build in docker for the first time(i thought the low TPS was due to docker ), now i build in centos 7, got the same result ;

this is one of the redis.conf, 6 in total

```
port 6383

#dbfilename dump.rdb
#save 300 10
save ""

appendonly yes
appendfilename appendonly.aof
# appendfsync always
appendfsync everysec
# appendfsync no

dir /home/chen/redis-hd/node6383/data

maxmemory 2G

logfile /home/chen/redis-hd/node6383/data/redis.log

protected-mode no

maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru

# bind 127.0.0.1

cluster-enabled yes

cluster-config-file nodes.conf 

cluster-node-timeout 15000 
cluster-slave-validity-factor 10 
cluster-migration-barrier 1 
cluster-require-full-coverage yes  

cluster-announce-ip 192.168.1.61
no-appendfsync-on-rewrite yes
```

i test one node redis, the tps is 2000,
why redis cluster'TPS is lower than singele node?
anybody can help me, i will be very appreciated!

Comment: Finily i change the redis version to 5.0.10, the problem resolved, bug i do not konw the interal quetion, keep lean